# Is SwingWorker the only way?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I have found that in order to keep Java GUIs (using Swing) responsive the only way is to use the SwingWorker class, as opposed to java.lang.Thread. Is SwingWorker truly the only way when it comes multithreaded GUI based desktop apps? Are there any good alternatives? Rarely can I configure the Thread class to do what I want to do, but SwingWorker usually works, if sometimes in a cumbersome way.

Comment: I guess you should read about the Swing thread model...

Comment: Are there any good alternatives? yes there isn't an issue to use plain vanilla Thread or Runnable#Thread, but output to Swing GUI (methods implemented in Swing APIs) should be wrapped into invokeLater(), then code flow is under control in compare with back holes (Future & bridge implemented in SwingWorkers API) in  SwingWorkers

Comment: You can use [`ExecutorService`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ExecutorService.html) for background processes.

Comment: You don't "have" to use Swingawtoker, but it makes this much easier. You can standard Threads, but you will become responsible for syncing updates to the UI to the EDT yourself using SwingUtilities.invokeLater

Comment: related question: stackoverflow.com/questions/21875192/swing-application-multithread-design-patterns-and-best-practices

Answer (score 9):

`SwingWorker` is nothing but a thin convenience API around `Thread`. Therefore it is definitely possible to use `Thread` without `SwingWorker`. The main point is that Swing is not thread-safe and any actions you perform on Swing objects must happen on the Event Dispatch Thread. This is the fundamental obstacle, and `SwingWorker` tries to help you overcome it a bit more conveniently.

Answer (score 7):

The alternative is a [*continuation*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuation_passing_style#Continuations_as_objects) using `EventQueue.invokeLater()`, but [`SwingWorker`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) has important advantages:

- It synchronizes granular access to data shared between itself and the EDT.
- It provides property change support for progress indication.
- It implements the [`Future`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html) interface.

See also [*Worker Threads and SwingWorker*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/worker.html) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Multithreading in GUI application is difficult to implement since there can be so many actions that trigger actions. A good explanation of why is this a "failed dream" can be found here 
[Multithreaded toolkits: A failed dream.](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/kgh/archive/2004/10/multithreaded_t.html). For solutions to your problem, read this article on concurrency in swing: [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/index.html)

Depending on your duration of the action you can go with SwingUtilities.invokeLater() or make a SwingWorker for tasks that take a long time to complete and run in background.
You must use this classes or else you may be in situations where a thread will block your entire application and may seem unresponsive to the user.

Answer (score 2):

Another option, most suitable for repetitive tasks, is `javax.swing.Timer` (it can be used for one-shot tasks as well).