# How to get a warning if some code is blocking the main thread in Java Swing?

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, event-dispatch-thread

I am fixing a big application that has lots of code that blocks the main thread by accessing the filesystem or the network, probably because the original developer did not get a warning from Java Swing when developing it.

Is there a way to get a warning if some code is blocking the main thread in Java Swing?

I would like to see https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StrictMode.html for Java Swing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45223828/230513). If this is not a duplicate, please edit your question to include a [mcve] that shows your revised approach based on the duplicates cited.

Comment: @trashgod The question you are citing was not a duplicate of this one, but of others. That question was removed anyway.

Comment: Voting to undelete that [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45223828/230513) as a useful reference for EDT violations.

Comment: [Profile](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2064427/230513) to characterize latency; use `SwingWorker`, [_et al._](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21905494/230513) to manage it, .

Comment: @trashgod I have undeleted that question, but please, give positive points to it or the admins will delete it.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not your down-voter; you might be able to salvage that question by addressing some particular approach you tried, e.g. `CheckThreadViolationRepaintManager`. I see now that this question is different; any progress profiling?